# How to Decode values in listView/cursor/adapter(from Database) / modify every item in list in android ?

Tags: java, android, listview, rsa

i working on my first app for android and i trying do this.
I have database with task info like name, deadline, etc. I have Encoded this data with rsa. Now i want show all task from database but i need to decode every value from list/cursor/adapter. I know how to do this when i select one item from DB, but when i select many i dont know how to modify them in cursor. I find something about that i cant modify cursor, so i dont know how can i do this.

This is my cursor:

```
private Cursor getAllTableTasks() {
    TaskDatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new TaskDatabaseOpenHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + YPWA.TaskList.TABLE_NAME + " list INNER JOIN " + YPWA.Task.TABLE_NAME + " task ON list.taskid=task._id WHERE list.email = ?", new String[]{LoginActivity.email});

    return cursor;
}
```

Here i want to decode data with my funcion Decode(String encodeddata) from AsymmetricAlgorithmRSA.class :

```
    ListView task_list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.taskListView);

    Cursor cursor = getAllTableTasks();
    String[] from = { YPWA.Task.NAME };

    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);

    AsymmetricAlgorithmRSA rsa = new AsymmetricAlgorithmRSA();

    task_list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Hope, you know what i want to do :D Thanks everybody.